# Javascript console output debug verbosity in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, logging, visual-studio-2013

I am developing a WP8 app, when I run the emulator that use JS code, the console.log is only shown but error and warn aren't.

There are the commands

```
    console.log('This line works');
    console.error('This line doesn't work');
    console.warn('This line doesn't work');
```

This is probably a problem with the Verbosity settings which I didn't find.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few buttons at the top of the console, assuming you're referring to the one inside Visual Studio itself.  They toggle the various message types Error, Warnings and Messages.

[image: Javascript Console inside Visual Studio 2013]